# How can I tell if a control is being visualized?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0

Is there a property (in WinForms) that allows me to tell whether a specific control is being visualized on the screen (even if partially)? That is,

- its Visible property is true, and
- it is not covered by other windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer possible on Vista and up with Aero enabled.  Windows are visible in for example window thumbnails and Aero Peek, even if they are overlapped by other windows.  Rely on Windows asking for paints, don't try to optimize them.  And use Invalidate() if you have a reason to repaint, never paint directly.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the Paint event is firing is probably your best bet.

```
private void myControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  this.Text = "Painted at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```